# stop nginx redirecting to /public folder

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I'm hosting a VM at `192.168.33.10` and configured my webroot to `/home/vagrant/www`.

Within this I've placed an `index.php`. Navigating to `192.168.33.10/index.php` serves the file, but navigating to `192.168.33.10` always redirects to `192.168.33.10/public`

How do I disable this public redirect?

EDIT - included  '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default':

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /home/vagrant/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file in the same directory as index.php? That could be causing a redirect?

Comment: no this is a fresh install - apache is not installed or ever been used

Comment: **check nginx.conf**!

Comment: I've checked nginx.conf - the word 'public' isn't mentioned at all. This is a fresh install of nginx using apt-get. The original index.html was served from 192.168.33.10/public even though it doesn't exist

Comment: Do a system search of the entire site for public. It's probably hidden somewhere that you're overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, feel stupid. Chrome's browser was consistently autocompleting to `192.168.33.10/public`! - had to clear the cache and all is fine.. Unsure how to prevent this behaviour in Chrome